# capture a single value from an analog joystick

Tags: python

I am attempting to trigger an event with a particular value of an analog joystick y axis in a while loop.  I have used in an if statement ==, >, <, <>, >=  .  Because the readout (print y value) lags because of cycling, the value, once triggered, remains until the y value steps up and back down.  I really just want to snapshot the y value when it occurs to trigger another event.  I would then use another y value to stop the event that was previously triggered.  I have two processes going continually; one to handle this backup blinking function and the other to operate motors on robot via gamepad inputs.

suggestions please?

This code works properly if I ask for a user input, but can't get it to work using the joystick value as the trigger(above).

```py
from time import sleep

from inputs import get_gamepad

controller_input = {'ABS_Y': 0}


def left_thumb_joystick_d():

    # Function to Left Thumb Joystick to the UP-DOWN

    print('Left backward speed --> {}'.format(controller_input['ABS_Y']))

    print("Left motor Backward speeding up")


def gamepad_update():

    # Code execution stops at the following line until gamepad event occurs.

    events = get_gamepad()

    return_code = 'No Match'

    for event in events:

        event_test = controller_input.get(event.code, 'No Match')

        if event_test != 'No Match':

            controller_input[event.code] = event.state

            return_code = event.code

        else:

            return_code = 'No Match'

        return return_code


while True:

    control_code = gamepad_update()

    joystick_count = (controller_input['ABS_Y'])

    for i in range(joystick_count):
        joystick = (controller_input['ABS_Y'])
        joy = joystick
        print(joy)

        if 135 < joy < 145:
            n = 1
        #while joy == 145:
            print("repeating loop")
            while n > 0:
                print("hd_lights_on")
                print("tail_lights_on")
                sleep(.5)
                print("hd_lights_off")
                print("tail_lights_off")
                sleep(.5)
                n -= 1
                print(n)
                #n = int(input())
                #n = 0
                joy = 128
                break
        if joy == 128:
            n = 0
        break
```

Comment: How is a Pi involved? Place your code in a code block. What are you using to read the joystick value?

Comment: joystick motion is capture by the following at the top of the file

Comment: from time import sleep
from inputs import get_gamepad

controller_input = {'ABS_Y': 0}


def left_thumb_joystick_d():
    # Function to Left Thumb Joystick to the UP-DOWN
    print('Left backward speed --> {}'.format(controller_input['ABS_Y']))
    print("Left motor Backward speeding up")

Comment: def gamepad_update():
    # Code execution stops at the following line until gamepad event occurs.
    events = get_gamepad()
    return_code = 'No Match'
    for event in events:
        event_test = controller_input.get(event.code, 'No Match')
        if event_test != 'No Match':
            controller_input[event.code] = event.state
            return_code = event.code
        else:
            return_code = 'No Match'

        return return_code

Comment: Edit your question with this code in code blocks. How is a Pi involved?

Comment: Sorry Mike.  I don't know what you mean "How is a Pi involved?"  This is running on a Raspberry Pi 3+

Comment: Ok, amend your question with all this information.

Comment: Tried the threading--puts the pi in a loop and keyboard interrupt won't stop it.  Had to reboot.

Comment: Ctrl-C doesn't stop it? Do you use Thonny to write your Python code?

Comment: CoderMike, I am using PyCharm as the editor

Answer (score 1):

Does the following help?

What do you want to happen based on the Y value?

Tested on my Pi400 with XBox360 wired controller.

Edit: Added a reverse blinking thread

```
from inputs import get_gamepad
import threading,time

def blinkFunc():
    global reverse
    while True:
        if reverse:
            print("light on")
            time.sleep(0.5)
            print("light off")
        time.sleep(0.05)
        
reverse = False

blinkThread=threading.Thread(target = blinkFunc)
blinkThread.start()

while True:
    events = get_gamepad()
    for event in events:
        if event.code == "ABS_Y":
            #print(event.state)
            if event.state > 4000:
                reverse = True
                print("Backwards")
            elif event.state < -4000:
                print("Forwards")
            else:
                reverse = False
```

Comment: Mike,  that does work when I substituted my gamepad values, ie. 128 neutral, <128 forward, and >128 backwards.  However, when I insert the blinking while loop under the print ("Backwards") statement, the result is a follows>  Notice the counting up of the print(event.state).  Because of the lag in the capture of the value from the joystick the loop continues until the value finally works its way back to 128.  see below

Comment: 0
160
Backwards
hd_lights_on
tail_lights_on
hd_lights_off
tail_lights_off
0
173
Backwards
hd_lights_on
tail_lights_on
hd_lights_off
tail_lights_off
0
183
Backwards
hd_lights_on
tail_lights_on
hd_lights_off
tail_lights_off
0
190
Backwards
hd_lights_on
tail_lights_on
hd_lights_off
tail_lights_off
0
201
Backwards
hd_lights_on
tail_lights_on
hd_lights_off
tail_lights_off
0
212
Backwards
hd_lights_on
tail_lights_on
hd_lights_off
tail_lights_off
0
220
Backwards
hd_lights_on
tail_lights_on

Comment: the 0 is n value after going through the loop, the3 digit number is the event.state as it lags in reading the value

Comment: thank you for your help so far, as you can see, I am just trying to trigger a back blinking sequence when the robot is moving backwards.

Comment: then stop the sequence when the joystick if neutral or going forward

Comment: Added a thread for the reverse blinking